# How do `do` and `where` mix?

Tags: haskell

From some book I have the following code snippets

```
mutableUpdateIO :: Int -> IO (MV.MVector RealWorld Int)
mutableUpdateIO n = do
  mvec <- GM.new (n + 1)
  go n mvec
  where
    go 0 v = return v
    go n v = (MV.write v n 0) >> go (n - 1) v

mutableUpdateST :: Int -> V.Vector Int
mutableUpdateST n =
  runST $ do
    mvec <- GM.new (n + 1)
    go n mvec
  where
    go 0 v = V.freeze v
    go n v = (MV.write v n 0) >> go (n - 1) v
```

like `hindent` indents them. Now I want to introduce all braces and semicolons, so the whitespace isn't relevant any more. Just because I am curious.

The second example suggests, that the `where` belongs to the whole `runST $ do ...` expression, but the first example suggests, that the where is somehow a part of the `go n mvec` statement. Reading in [Haskell Report Chapter 2.7](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7) I tried to introduce braces and semicolons in the first example like

```
mutableUpdateIO :: Int -> IO (MV.MVector RealWorld Int)
mutableUpdateIO n = do {
  mvec <- GM.new (n + 1);
  go n mvec;
  where {
    go 0 v = return v;
    go n v = (MV.write v n 0) >> go (n - 1) v;
  } ; }
```

But I get a parsing error. Why is that?

Why is the layout `hindent` produces for the first example `mutableUpdateIO` valid Haskell? Shouldn't the braces and semicolons be introduced like in my above try?

Comment: `where` is separate from the `do` afaik. I think where's automatically have function scope.

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721354/in-haskell-what-is-the-scope-of-a-where-clause-when-dealing-with-guards

Comment: `do ...` is an expression. `where` never attaches to expressions, only to declarations.

Comment: `do { ..; where { .. } }` is never valid, because as @melpomene says, `where` is never associated with an expression. The first program with explicit layout is `do { .. } where { .. }`

Comment: For what it is worth, in my personal style I never mix `do` and `where`. More in general, I try to avoid `where` except after `... = expr` with `expr` being 1 or at most 2 lines long. Since `do` is longer than that, `where` is avoided. Further, `do` allows `let` inside it, so one can use that instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `where` blocks belong neither to the `runST $ do ...` expression nor to the `go n mvec` statement; they belong to the `mutableUpdateIO n = ...` declaration and the `mutableUpdateST n = ...` declaration. The braces and semicolons should go like this:

```
mutableUpdateIO :: Int -> IO (MV.MVector RealWorld Int)
mutableUpdateIO n = do {
  mvec <- GM.new (n + 1);
  go n mvec;
  } where {
    go 0 v = return v;
    go n v = (MV.write v n 0) >> go (n - 1) v;
  }
```

The relevant sentence from the informal description in the Report in chapter 2.7 is this:

> A close brace is also inserted whenever the syntactic category containing the layout list ends; that is, if an illegal lexeme is encountered at a point where a close brace would be legal, a close brace is inserted.

Since `where` is an illegal lexeme inside an expression, this ends the `do` block and a close brace is inserted there. This also explains why the layout hindent produced was legal.