# Why this variable is invisible in where

Tags: haskell, monads

I want to read a matrix `[[Int]]` from a text file(this matrix is given in 
 a [project euler's problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11)), so I have the following code

```
parseInt :: String -> [Int]
parseInt [] = []
parseInt (x : xs) = [(ord x) - (ord '0')] ++ (parseInt xs)

main = do
  str <- readFile "11.dat" 
  print $ fmap parseInt (lines str)
```

this code works fine and I can output the matrix a read.

However, I want to change the `main` function, so I can reuse `fmap parseInt (lines str)` instead of repeating it in my code.

```
main = do
  str <- readFile "11.dat" 
  print b
  where b = fmap parseInt (lines str)
```

the compiler gives me an error

```
11.hs:37:34: error:
    Variable not in scope: str :: String
[Finished in 0.9s]
```

It seems that the feed operation `str <- readFile "11.dat"` causes this problem because when I read from a string directly the code works fine

```
main = do
  print b
  where b = fmap parseInt (lines "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08\n...01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48\n")
```

I can also with `let`

```
main = do
  str <- readFile "11.dat" 
  let b = fmap parseInt (lines str)
  print b
```

So how can I do that with `that`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45306764/625403 was recently asked, which is another way to come to the same realization provided in pigworker's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a parsing issue. Haskell parses the offending code as

```
main = (do {str <- readFile "11.dat"; print b}) where {b = fmap parseInt (lines str)}
```

so that the only local variables in scope for the `where` clause are the pattern variables to the left of `=` (all none of them, but in general, you might have some).

Meanwhile `str` scopes only from its binding to the end of the `do` block. And that's why putting a `let` in the `do` block after that binding works just fine.

Comment: thank you very much for pointing out and correcting my error. Following your advise, I did some search, and I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274650/in-haskell-when-do-we-use-in-with-let) maybe also a good reading

Comment: Another common fix is to make `b` a function and pass it `str` as an argument.